# Glide, como puedo cargar una URL cuando este disponible

Tags: android, glide

tengo este codigo en un adapter:

```
  Glide.with(viewHolder.itemView)
                    .load(url[1])
                    .into(viewHolder.imageViewBackground);
```

Quiero cargar la imagen pero cuando este disponible el link de la url. ¿Hay Alguna menera?

Comment: Es un recyclerview donde cargas la imagen verdad?

Comment: Ya lo solucione gracias de todas maneras, cree un fragmento para hacer de pantalla de carga, y de esa manera ya tengo las urls antes de solicitarlas.

Answer (score 0):

La única forma de cargarla cuando este disponible es que la vista sea destruida y la vuelvas a agregar al mostrarla nuevamente en pantalla, por ejemplo si usas un `RecyclerView` la vista puede destruirse si esta sale completamente de pantalla, al regresar creara nuevamente la vista y realizará la petición.

Mientras tanto, puedes validar si no existe la imagen, no trate de cargarla:

```
if(url[1] != null || && !url[1].trim().equals("")){
     Glide.with(viewHolder.itemView)
                    .load(url[1])
                    .into(viewHolder.imageViewBackground);

    }
```